# Integration test and hosting ASP.NET Core 6.0 without Startup class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

To setup unit tests in previous versions of .NET Core, I could host my web App or web API in a test project the following way:

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(config =>
    {
        config.UseStartup<MyWebApp.Startup>();
        config.UseUrls("https://localhost:44331/");
        ...    
    })
    .Build();
```

The current .NET 6.0 does not use `Startup` class concept, and thus it could not be referenced. How can host ASP.NET Core apps in a test project in a proper and clean way?

Comment: I have a repo showing the use of `WebApplicationFactory<T>` for unit/integration tests with Minimal APIs, maybe that will help you out: https://github.com/martincostello/dotnet-minimal-api-integration-testing

Comment: @martin-costello I see the trick is adding `public partial class Program{}`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Note that you can switch to generic hosting model (the one using the startup class) if you want.

To set up integration tests with the [new minimal hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#new-hosting-model) you can make web project internals visible to the test one for example by adding next property to csproj:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <InternalsVisibleTo Include="YourTestProjectName"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

And then you can use the `Program` class generated for the web app in `WebApplicationFactory`:

```
class MyWebApplication : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        // shared extra set up goes here
        return base.CreateHost(builder);
    }
}
```

And then in the test:

```
var application = new MyWebApplication();
var client = application.CreateClient();
var response = await client.GetStringAsync("/api/WeatherForecast");
```

Or use `WebApplicationFactory<Program>` from the test directly:

```
var application = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>()
    .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
           // set up servises
        });
    });
var client = application.CreateClient();
var response = await client.GetStringAsync("/api/WeatherForecast");
```

Or instead of using `InternalsVisibleTo` you can declare public partial `Program` class and use it. For example add next to the bottom of top-level statement file (the rest is the same):

```cs
public partial class Program { }
```

Code examples from [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0#test-with-webapplicationfactory-or-testserver).

Comment: Any idea on how to do this without using WebApplicationFactory or TestServer? Asking as I'm trying to implement PactNet provider tests, and have yet to figure this out https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net

Comment: @ImerMuhović did you ever get this solved for Pact?

Comment: @Aaron you can try looking into options listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74561335/2501279)

Comment: @GuruStron Thank you! putting public partial class Program { } and the class MyWebApplication : WebApplicationFactory<Program> worked for me