# How to Use ASP NET 6 Testing WebApplicationFactory to start web server for testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I been trying to make `WebApplicationFactory<Program>` to start HTTP server to do end-to-end like testing. I have tried overriding various methods and trying to add kestrel to make it listen on HTTP TCP socket.

Most approaches online seem to be building custom WebHostBuilder and injecting `Startup` class, but I am using minimal APIs, so `Startup` class is not present for me.

By default `WebApplicationFactory` seems to make test server that only works with a http client class and do not listen on HTTP port. [As descried by question asked here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70093628/integration-test-and-hosting-asp-net-core-6-0-without-startup-class)

And yes I need HTTP server, I am using Playwright to do testing. Or at last trying to.

Comment: If you are testing with an external test engine and you need the full HTTP pipeline, then why don't you host the service at a staging/testing location or simply run it locally for the tests. If you are not able to use the `HttpClient` reference testing methodology, then you might as well run the real site.

Comment: I can't even edit this to salvage it. Playwright is used to test published web sites/services, the advice you have been reading is about how to start a local instance of your site for unit-testing purposes which you have already stated is inappropriate. So you shouldn't really be trying to do this at all. So while the tagged question is not a dup, I can't vote to re-open in this state.