# How to access the top-level statement variable in a class in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, .net-5, c#-9.0, toplevel-statement

I have a simple code below. I want to access the variable `x` in the class `Program`. As `x` is a global variable, I should be able to access it, Is there a way to access the top-level variable apart from the top level?

```
int x = 0;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {

        public void TestMethod()
        {
            int y = x;
        }
    }
}
```

**Error message:**

> CS8801    Cannot use local variable or local function 'x' declared in a
> top-level statement in this context

Is the below only allowed? I mean to access at the top level only?

```
int x = 0;
int z = x; //no compilation error?
```

**Edit**: `int y = global::x;` also gives compilation error

Comment: Per the [spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/top-level-statements), "If any top-level statements are present in any compilation unit of the program, the meaning is as if they were combined in the block body of a `Main` method of a `Program` class in the global namespace". Your variable is therefore local to this method, meaning it can't be accessed anywhere outside of it, which would require a member. In general, top-level statements should only be considered as a simpler way of writing `Main`, and not mixed with explicit `Main`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the below only allowed? I mean to access at the top level only?

Yes, top-level statements actually generate a method and all declared variables are local to it. I.e. your code will be translated to something like the following ([@sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APglgdgLgAgB4ILwIAwG4CwAofGAQwFsBTAZwAciBjMhAYQHsYLmAbMgQSqoEZ8Ab3wIxCWHDIAnYhwQABAEyL+AdlHiRecbsUBmRQBYEAFUpwAsmTgALZsAAUASk16E29+4D03yQgBPNGRcHS8AXzcESLxwoA=)):

```cs
[CompilerGenerated]
internal class Program
{
    private static void <Main>$(string[] args)
    {
        int num = 0;
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public void TestMethod()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that actual generated class/method names can depend on the framework/SDK/compiler version, because in .NET 6 the generational pattern changed, as I understand to support [integration tests for ASP.NET Core with minimal hosting model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70093628/integration-test-and-hosting-asp-net-core-6-0-without-startup-class/70095604#70095604).

More info about the generation patterns can be found [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/top-level-statements#semantics).

Comment: Reminder - "cause" or "cos" is not an abbreviation of "because". Please use the full word - it is more readable this way, especially to people whose first language is not English.