# Separate Program.cs to Startup.cs in ASP.NET WebAPI Minimal for Integration testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, integration-testing, minimal-apis

I am trying to write integration tests for my web service.

I want to separate `Program.cs` into `Startup.cs` so test class can mock `TestStartup.cs`(or something like so). The point is swapping real services with mock services.

Attempt to use `Startup.cs` file for MinimalApi resulting `app` not compilable:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {
    (...)
    // Error CS1929  'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for
    // 'MapGroup' and the best extension method overload 'EndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapGroup(IEndpointRouteBuilder, string)'
    // requires a receiver of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.IEndpointRouteBuilder'
    app.MapGroup("/product").MapProductApi().WithTags("Product");
    app.UseResponseCaching();
    app.UseOutputCache();
}
```

Am I going the right direction? Should Minimal Apis be used with `Startup.cs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reconfigure the services with the usual test setup (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70095604/2501279) for more details):

```cs
var application = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>()
    .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            // set up servises
            services.RemoveAll(typeof(RegisteredServiceTypeToReplace));
            // add new registration for RegisteredServiceTypeToReplace
        });
    });
```

As for :

> // Error CS1929  'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'MapGroup'...

You can try using `UseEndpoints`:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(routeBuilder =>
{
    routeBuilder.MapGroup(...);
    // ...
})
```

Comment: What if we we don't want to rely on ASPNet.MVC library? is there another class to inject Program into it?

Comment: @MarwaAhmad  _"What if we we don't want to rely on ASPNet.MVC library"_ - can you please elaborate?

Comment: Guru Stron: The WebApplicationFactory exists in ASPNET.MVC library, and we don't want to use it, we want to use what exist in ASPNetCore and Azure.Function only.

Comment: @MarwaAhmad still not sure why. The class I've used comes from  [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing/8.0.3), not `ASPNET.MVC` library. And I don't see any issues using it in test project.